# Simple Makefile to build and run scala program

Tags: makefile

I wrote this simple Makefile but it ended up like a *spaghetti* code. I used `basename` multiple times. I have a special case for `first.spec.scala.run` and `follow.spec.scala.run` and maybe more antipattern code that I am not aware of. I am not happy with my code and I appreciate any feedback or review. Thank you.

```
SPECS=First Follow
EXAMPLES_PATH=../..
ROOT_PATH=../${EXAMPLES_PATH}
SCALAV=2.12
APSLIB=${ROOT_PATH}/lib/aps-library-${SCALAV}.jar
SCALA_FLAGS=.:${APSLIB}
APS2SCALA=${ROOT_PATH}/bin/aps2scala

all: $(addsuffix Spec.compile, $(SPECS)) $(addsuffix Spec.run, $(SPECS))

%.generate:
    ${APS2SCALA} -DCOT -p ${EXAMPLES_PATH}:${ROOT_PATH}/base $*

%.run:
    @scala -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@)

GrammarUtil.compile: grammar.generate
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} grammar.scala $(basename $@).scala

first.compile:
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

follow.compile:
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

Spec.compile:
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

FirstSpec.compile: Spec.compile grammar.generate GrammarUtil.compile first.generate first.compile
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

FollowSpec.compile: Spec.compile grammar.generate GrammarUtil.compile follow.generate follow.compile
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $@).scala

clean:
    rm -f *.class grammar.scala first.scala follow.scala
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Scala, but I do know Make, so I hope this helps.

Firstly, the makefile is missing `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:`, which pretty much every makefile needs, to avoid part-written output files appearing up-to-date when a compilation command fails (e.g. is interrupted).

We also want `.PHONY:` for those targets that don't produce files, such as `all` and `clean`.  (And clean should use `$(RM)` rather than `rm -f`, for increased portability.)

I think that we want a straightforward pattern rule that says that we can make a file called `foo.compile` given an input called `foo.scala`:

```
%.compile: %.scala
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $<
```

It looks to me that `-cp` is one of the flags to `scalac`, so that should probably be in `${SCALA_FLAGS}` rather than in the command.

I'm not convinced that your rules actually create the files they claim to.  For example, `GrammarUtil.compile` depends on `grammar.generate`, but then actually uses `grammar.scala` - should `grammar.generate` actually be `grammar.scala` there?

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback but I am failing. I am getting an error: https://gist.github.com/amir734jj/645a94412475dfb700f6116dd1c7e1bc

Comment: The error I am getting: "make: *** No rule to make target 'grammar.aps'. Stop."

Comment: Yes, I do. `%.generate` and `%.class` exist and running them individually works.

Comment: I've commented at that link (since that's not part of the review)